# Getting a single screenshot of browser using getDisplayMedia without prompting user

Tags: javascript, get-display-media

I am building an online app and on click of a button I want to be able to screenshot what the user sees in their browser(my app).  I've looked at lots of js libraries such as html2canvas, CCapture as dom-to-image but my page will have a mixture of html, svg, canvas and webgl content and none of the solutions I have found seem to capture it perfectly.

I then came across the [Screen Capture API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture) and getDisplayMedia.

All examples I can find always ask which tab/application/screen you want to share then have a live stream of your chosen page.

Ideally I don't want the user to do anything other than click the capture button and it to capture a single image (data url) of the page that the user initiated the function on.  I can then use that dataurl elsewhere.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You cannot achieve it by using getDisplayMedia. Because you cannot use these apis until user allowed you...

Comment: thanks for the response, is there anyway for them to allow once and remember?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You want to capture browser tab or full screen?

Comment: just the tab with my app in

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60231897/826815? Trying to get the same than you, did you solve it?

Comment: getDisplayMedia will only work with secure (Https) url

Answer (score -5):

Download the example from below url

https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Capture-HTML-Elements-Screenshot.html

and replace index.html with below code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>jQuery HTML Element Screenshot Example</title>
    <link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
.container { margin: 150px auto; }
        .container > div {
            padding: 20px;
            border: 5px solid black;
        }

        h2 {
            margin: 10px auto;
        }
label { margin: 10px auto; }
        .toPic {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="divTest">
    <div id="jquery-script-menu">
<div class="jquery-script-center">
<ul>
<li><a href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Capture-HTML-Elements-Screenshot.html">Download This Plugin</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/">Back To jQueryScript.Net</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="jquery-script-clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="container">
    <h1>jQuery HTML Element Screenshot Example</h1>
    <div style="background:red;width: 600px;" class="test">
        <div style="background:green;">
            <div style="background:blue;">
                <div style="background:yellow;">
                    <div style="background:orange;">
                        Element To Capture
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
    <h2 class="toCanvas"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger"> To Canvas </a></h2>
    <h2 class="toPic"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger"> To Image </a></h2>
    <h5>
       <label for="imgW">Image Width:</label>
<input type="number" id="imgW" placeholder="Image Width" class="form-control" value="600">
<label for="imgH">Image Height:</label>
<input type="number" id="imgH" placeholder="Image Height" class="form-control" value="73">
<label for="imgFileName">File Name:</label>
<input type="text" value="a" placeholder="File Name" id="imgFileName" class="form-control">
<label for="sel">File Type:</label>
<select id="sel" class="form-control">
  <option value="png" selected>png</option>
  <option value="jpeg">jpeg</option>
  <option value="bmp">bmp</option>
</select>
<button id="save" class="btn btn-danger">Save And Download</button>
    </h5>
</div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="canvas2image.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var test = $("#divTest").get(0);
        // to canvas
$('.toCanvas').click(function(e) {
  html2canvas(test).then(function(canvas) {
    // canvas width
    var canvasWidth = $('#divTest').width();
    // canvas height
    var canvasHeight = $('#divTest').height();
    // render canvas
    $('.toCanvas').after(canvas);
    // show 'to image' button
    $('.toPic').show(1000);
    // convert canvas to image
    $('.toPic').click(function(e) {
      var img = Canvas2Image.convertToImage(canvas, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
      // render image
      $(".toPic").after(img);
      // save
      $('#save').click(function(e) {
        let type = $('#sel').val(); // image type
        //let w = $('#imgW').val(); // image width
        //let h = $('#imgH').val(); // image height

        let w = canvasWidth; // image width
        let h = canvasHeight; // image height
        let f = $('#imgFileName').val(); // file name
        w = (w === '') ? canvasWidth : w;
        h = (h === '') ? canvasHeight : h;
        // save as image
        Canvas2Image.saveAsImage(canvas, w, h, type, f);
      });
    });
  });
});
    </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And run index.html in browser. Click on To Canvas button then click on To Image button and finally click on download.

And let me know if it's same you are looking for

Comment: I can see that's using html2canvas.  As i mentioned in my initial post, I have tried this and it doesn't capture my svgs correctly

Comment: You will probably find difficulties whenever you try to use some plugin into your app. You should focus on the solve the issue instead of shifting plguin or libraries. 

Can you please make a fiddle of your page, so I can see what's wrong with svgs?

Comment: html2canvas does not work. It mimics the webpage, it is not a screenshot. This is not a solution, it is a hack.